# django - date filter without bloat

Tags: python, django

I need to perform a filter by date with a form where if one of the date parameters is suppressed the upper/lower border of the date range is not being set in filter (which means min possible date/max possible date, respectively)

My code is:

```
#forms.py
...
start_date = forms.DateField(
        required=False,
)
end_date = forms.DateField(
        required=False
)
...

# views.py
def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
    form = self.request.GET

    if form.is_valid():
        cd = form.cleaned_data
        if not cd['start_date']:
            start_date = datetime.date(1,1,1)
        else:
            start_date = cd['start_date']

        if not cd['end_date']:
            end_date = datetime.date(3000,1,1)
        else:
            start_date = cd['end_date']

        MyC.objects.filter(date__range=(start_date,end_date))
```

This code works but looks very cludgy to me (Many senseless if clauses, duplicate code, etc).

Maybe there is a Filter function for this case (if start date is None -> don't filter)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply the filters as needed. The query won't happen until you use the queryset.

```
objects = MyC.objects.all()
if cd['start_date']:
    objects = objects.filter(date__gt=cd['start_date'])
if cd['end_date']:
    objects = objects.filter(date__lt=cd['end_date'])
return objects
```

Answer (score 0):

if you need default dates you can do:

```
start_date = self.cleaned_data.get('start_date', datetime.date(1,1,1))
end_date = self.cleaned_data.get('end_date', datetime.date(3000,1,1))

 MyC.objects.filter(date__range=(start_date, end_date))
```

Comment: This would not help my needs, as `start_date` ist in the dictionary as None

Comment: Yes, this is the reason why I said that if you want you can set a DEFAULT value